How release my complement WearOS Android Native app to Play Store
I have two apps, one for mobile and a new one for wearOS, my mobile app is currently in Play Store and I need release my Wear OS app. Both apps are in the same project in different modules and use functions and classes that are in different modules too (for example, commonModels).
But I don't know if is necessary generate two app bundles (one for the mobile app and another one for the Wear OS app) or if it is enough with one generated for mobile app.
Which is the correct path to release my new Wear OS app?

Two bundles, one for each... then you release each one on its own track inside the play console...

You need to upload a separate app bundle for each form factor (e.g. Wear OS, mobile, etc.)
